# Elliptic linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a rather short question:

> > What does "elliptic" mean in the the context of linear ODE?

Only found "elliptic" in the context of partial differential equations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elliptic partial differential equations and elliptic operators](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857899/elliptic-partial-differential-equations-and-elliptic-operators)

Comment: @ConradoCosta That question is about PDE.

Comment: Your chances of getting a helpful answer would increase if you gave a reference to a source that users the term "elliptic ODE". Generally, when your question is so short... think of what you neglected to include.

Answer (score 1):

Classification of second order linear (or semi linear) PDE's into elliptic, hyperbolic or parabolic depends on the quadratic form attached to the principal part of the equation:
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}\longleftrightarrow\sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}\xi_i\xi_j.
$$

For a second order linear ODE the principal part is just $y''$ and the quadratic form $\xi^2$. In a certain sense all second order linear ODE's are elliptic.